# Find which dependencies of the application are missing

Tags: c#

How to verify that all dependencies of the application are located in a folder (not in GAC)?

For example we have an application A with four dependencies: B, C, D, E.

After build we have a folder:

```
\ForDeployment\A.exe
\ForDeployment\B.dll
\ForDeployment\E.dll
```

For some reason two assemblies (C and D) are not located in the folder.

How can I determine which assemblies are missing from the folder? We are looking for a code or a command-line tool, which can be launched on every build.

EDIT:

Changing "Copy local" setting is not relevant because:

- I have hundred solutions. Any developer at any time may change this setting to the wrong one (or add new dependency with "Copy local"="false"). The tool I'm looking for should resolve this problem too
- The dependency located in GAC will never be copied to result folder (in VS2010)

Answer (score 1):

Just set **Copy Local** to `true` for the dependencies in question. That way you'll be sure to have a copy of the assembly locally.

Comment: I have no control on project files, but I need to know that after the build the application has all its dependencies in the folder. Another problem is when the dependency is located in GAC, "Copy Local" doesn't work in this case (VS2010)

Comment: So you can add a post build event but you can't change an attribute for a reference... seems like you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't use any post-build events. I have hundred solutions and can't (and don't want to) change them. Any developer may mistakenly set "Copy Local" to false or put the dependency in GAC - as a result this dependency will be missed in result folder.

Comment: So instead you will run something to verify if all the assemblies are present, which is something you will have to continue to manage as things evolve instead of making sure when the build is done it's configured correctly. Seems like you're making it more difficult.

Comment: Exactly. I want to run something to know that all assemblies are present. It was exactly my question. One of reasons is assemblies in GAC. What should I define to get these dependencies in result folder (VS2010)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do an something like:

```
if(!FileExist)
     Output message "Missing File"
```

And just run do that for each dependency file every time you launch the program.  But I'd just follow Gabe's advice in the comment and set Copy Local to true on all dependencies.